# A trigger for generating unique incrementing value that starts as 1 annually with the two digit year as prefex in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.2

The particular postgres database table has 21 fields one of which is set for sequence as a primary key "repair_id". The other unique field called "repair_accession" is also a special unique TEXT in a format like "NH13-1".

I am looking for a reliable trigger function for generating unique number based on two letters, two digit year format, and an auto-increment number that resets to 1 annually on Jan 1st.

Example: for 2013 = NH13-1 up-to NH13-999999

and on January 1st 2014, it will reset itself and starts as NH14-1 up to NH14-999999

etc.

Your answer is much apprecaited!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version you are using, but I'm assuming from the Tag that it's 9.2.  IMO, you are gonna need a combination of things here:

- a sequencer
- a before insert trigger
- a cron job (or similar event) to reset your sequencer at the start of the new year

Search and review documentation for:

- `Create Sequencer`
- `nextval` (to get the next value for generating the id)
- `setval` (to reset via the cron job)
- `date_part` (to get the year)

Basically, in your trigger, you will get the year via date_part and store it in a var (e.g. the_year), then:

```
NEW.repair_accession := 'NH'||the_year::text||'-'||nextval({{name of sequencer}})::text;
```

note: solution or code has not been tested.  If you end up using this as the answer, I request that you update this answer with your actual code and remove this note.

One final suggest, if you are going to have to sort by this value, then I suggest you pad the value from the sequencer with zeros.  For example:

NH13-0000100 (instead of HN13-100).  This is probably not needed if you timestamp each record on insert.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will do that and update this. I am using version 9.2, you assumed right.

Comment: I found this link on stackoverflow and ended up using it
Thanks for your suggestion though!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598959/custom-auto-increment-field-in-postgresql-invoice-order-no