# max function to increment a key field

Tags: postgresql

Is it safe to use the max function in order to get the next value of a field like it is being done here?

[Custom auto-increment field in postgresql (Invoice/Order No.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598959/custom-auto-increment-field-in-postgresql-invoice-order-no/)

I ask this because I need to generate something similar but will the max function returns always a different value for concurrent users? I undertand that a trigger is being used, but again, I dont understand how a max function may be safe here. If not, what should be used?

thank you!

Comment: This seems dangerous, because between one session's read of the MAX and its eventual COMMIT, any other number of sessions could have read the same MAX. Can you use a sequence instead? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: Why not use sequence?

Comment: so, my point seems correct. I would like to have a counter that starts from 1 for each year. I would like to have this logic on the database. But I dont know how to achieve that with a sequence. If I need something like "year+month+sequence" and if I dont have my key like this, then how could I easily find records if from my application I will have the whole value and not only the sequence number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is not safe. There is no guarantee that two concurrent sessions do not get the same max value and will try to insert a row with the same number.

Using a serial column (or a sequence explicitly) is a better option. It ensures that you receive unique values, but does not guarantee that they will be successive, see [PostgreSQL - next serial value in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18233092/1995738).

If this last condition must be retained you can use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#advisory-locks) to use the `max()` function for this purpose, e.g.:

```
begin;
select pg_advisory_xact_lock('my_table'::regclass::bigint);
-- a concurrent session waits here until the transaction completes
insert into my_table (id)
select max(id)+ 1 from my_table;
commit;
```

You can also use [explicit lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html) in access exclusive mode for the table, however the negative impact of advisory locks on server performance is lower.