# Encrypt an integer to get only numeric characters in JAVA

Tags: java, encryption, alphanumeric

I have a database id that start from 1 to ... and I need encrypt this number to use for pursuit number.
how to generate numeric string by encrypting the database id and decrypt it?
pursuit number must be short as possible.

Comment: Lets see if I understood you... you want to generate another Int (encrypted) from an Int, and be able to decrypt it back?

Comment: I won't mark this as dupe, but it's similar: [Obscure / encrypt an order number as another number: symmetrical, “random” appearance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/611915/342852)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How secure do you need this encryption to be?  A simple XOR with another int might be what you need, though you might have to be careful with sign bits.

Alternatively, if you want something more secure, just implement a simple 32 bit Feistel cypher.  Here's one I prepared earlier:

```
/**
 * IntegerPerm is a reversible keyed permutation of the integers.
 * This class is not cryptographically secure as the F function
 * is too simple and there are not enough rounds.
 *
 * @author Martin Ross
 */
public final class IntegerPerm {

    //////////////////
    // Private Data //
    //////////////////

    /** Non-zero default key, from www.random.org */
    private final static int DEFAULT_KEY = 0x6CFB18E2;

    private final static int LOW_16_MASK = 0xFFFF;
    private final static int HALF_SHIFT = 16;
    private final static int NUM_ROUNDS = 4;

    /** Permutation key */
    private int mKey;

    /** Round key schedule */
    private int[] mRoundKeys = new int[NUM_ROUNDS];

    //////////////////
    // Constructors //
    //////////////////
    public IntegerPerm() { this(DEFAULT_KEY); }

    public IntegerPerm(int key) { setKey(key); }

    ////////////////////
    // Public Methods //
    ////////////////////
    /** Sets a new value for the key and key schedule. */
    public void setKey(int newKey) {
        assert (NUM_ROUNDS == 4) : "NUM_ROUNDS is not 4";
        mKey = newKey;

        mRoundKeys[0] = mKey & LOW_16_MASK;
        mRoundKeys[1] = ~(mKey & LOW_16_MASK);
        mRoundKeys[2] = mKey >>> HALF_SHIFT;
        mRoundKeys[3] = ~(mKey >>> HALF_SHIFT);
    } // end setKey()

    /** Returns the current value of the key. */
    public int getKey() { return mKey; }

    /**
     * Calculates the enciphered (i.e. permuted) value of the given integer
     * under the current key.
     *
     * @param plain the integer to encipher.
     *
     * @return the enciphered (permuted) value.
     */
    public int encipher(int plain) {
        // 1 Split into two halves.
        int rhs = plain & LOW_16_MASK;
        int lhs = plain >>> HALF_SHIFT;

        // 2 Do NUM_ROUNDS simple Feistel rounds.
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROUNDS; ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                // Swap lhs <-> rhs
                final int temp = lhs;
                lhs = rhs;
                rhs = temp;
            } // end if
            // Apply Feistel round function F().
            rhs ^= F(lhs, i);
        } // end for

        // 3 Recombine the two halves and return.
        return (lhs << HALF_SHIFT) + (rhs & LOW_16_MASK);
    } // end encipher()


    /**
     * Calculates the deciphered (i.e. inverse permuted) value of the given
     * integer under the current key.
     *
     * @param cypher the integer to decipher.
     *
     * @return the deciphered (inverse permuted) value.
     */
    public int decipher(int cypher) {
        // 1 Split into two halves.
        int rhs = cypher & LOW_16_MASK;
        int lhs = cypher >>> HALF_SHIFT;

        // 2 Do NUM_ROUNDS simple Feistel rounds.
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROUNDS; ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                // Swap lhs <-> rhs
                final int temp = lhs;
                lhs = rhs;
                rhs = temp;
            } // end if
            // Apply Feistel round function F().
            rhs ^= F(lhs, NUM_ROUNDS - 1 - i);
        } // end for

        // 4 Recombine the two halves and return.
        return (lhs << HALF_SHIFT) + (rhs & LOW_16_MASK);
    } // end decipher()

    /////////////////////
    // Private Methods //
    /////////////////////

    // The F function for the Feistel rounds.
    private int F(int num, int round) {
        // XOR with round key.
        num ^= mRoundKeys[round];
        // Square, then XOR the high and low parts.
        num *= num;
        return (num >>> HALF_SHIFT) ^ (num & LOW_16_MASK);
    } // end F()

} // end class IntegerPerm
```

Comment: cool thanks a lot. Very nice for in-place encrytion in a table storing integers. Put up a Python version of your code at https://gist.github.com/1404682

Comment: what if, i only want positive number for encrypted value?

Comment: If the returned number is negative, just add 2^32 for 32 bit integers (or 2^64 for 64 bit integers).  You will need to go up one size to fit the result without overflow.

Answer (score 1):

how about convert the Integer (DEC) -> Octal?

well, 1-7 will not be 'encrypted' in this way.

Comment: That's not exactly encryption.

Comment: You could just use the same value. Or value + 1. Encryption works only with a private key, or you lose the possibility of decryption (by generating a hash, for example)

Comment: well, I think it is a kind of encryption, but the algorithm is as simple as dec->octal. even original integer + a magic number could be called encryption as well. It depends on how secure the encrypted string/integer OP wants. I guess he just doesn't want the user know the real ID.

Comment: True, but what (security) benefits to you gain from such an _encryption_?

Comment: @michael667 as I said, it depends on security requirement of his application. If he wants a really "safe" algorithm, mine is not acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a nice cryptographically-secure random number generator, add a table to the database that relates IDs to their encrypted versions, and you're set.

Just generate a random number for each ID, ensure it's not already being used as an encrypted version of some other ID, and voila.

This will foil anyone who tries to crack the scheme you use, since you're effectively not using one.